# What subset of the SOAP and WSDL specification does PHP's SOAP extension support?

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

In the PHP manual:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.soap.php

```
The SOAP extension can be used to write SOAP Servers and Clients. 
It supports subsets of SOAP 1.1, SOAP 1.2 and WSDL 1.1 specifications.
```

Where can I find what subset of SOAP and WSDL specification the SOAP extension supports.

I'm interested in this information because my service provider (who targets dot net and java clients) keeps breaking my app when they change their WSDLs.

Any pointers for me?

Thanks

**Additional**

So this is what I'm getting:

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53234
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50997

So maybe just a php bug :(